# Only able to use getter method once

Tags: java

I'm working on a Java project in which I have the getter method below in the class TextAnalyzer:

```
public Hashtable<String, Double> getTotalFeatureOccurances() {
    return(feat_occur_total);
}//getTotalFeatureOccurances
```

I also have the private class variable:

```
private Hashtable<String, Double> feat_occur_total;
```

I use the getter, add more terms to the hash, and then want to get the hash again, however it always comes back empty.  Even worse if I don't add or remove anything from the hash, but do two gets, I still receive and empty hash the second time.

Here is my code in main:

```
TextAnalyzer ta = new TextAnalyzer();
        feat_occur_cat = ta.wordOccurancesCount(text, features);
        feat_occur_total = ta.getTotalFeatureOccurances();

        Enumeration<Double> e = feat_occur_total.elements();
        while(e.hasMoreElements()) {
            System.out.println(e.nextElement());
        }//while

        feat_occur_total.clear();
        feat_occur_total  = ta.getTotalFeatureOccurances();

        e = feat_occur_total.elements();
        System.out.println("\n\nSECOND GET\n\n");
        while(e.hasMoreElements()) {
            System.out.println(e.nextElement());
        }//while
```

I get the output:

```
2.0
1.0
5.0
1.0
1.0
3.0
2.0
3.0


SECOND GET
```

Here is the entire class:

```
public class TextAnalyzer {

    TextAnalyzer() {
        this.feat_occur_total = new Hashtable<String, Double>();
    }

    public String[][] wordOccurancesCount(String text, Vector<String> features) {
        String[][] occur = new String[features.size()][features.size()];

        for(int ndx=0; ndx<features.size(); ndx++) {
            int count=0;

            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:^|\\s+|\\()\\s*(" + features.elementAt(ndx).trim() + ")\\w*(?:,|\\.|\\)|\\s|$)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.CANON_EQ);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
            m.usePattern(p);

            while(m.find())
                count++;

            occur[ndx][0] = features.elementAt(ndx);
            occur[ndx][1] = String.valueOf(count);

            if(this.feat_occur_total.containsKey(features.elementAt(ndx))) {
                double temp = this.feat_occur_total.get(features.elementAt(ndx));
                temp += count;
                this.feat_occur_total.put(features.elementAt(ndx), temp);
            }//if
            else {
                this.feat_occur_total.put(features.elementAt(ndx), Double.valueOf(count));
            }//else
        }//for

        return(occur);
    }//word

    public Hashtable<String, Double> getTotalFeatureOccurances() {
        return(feat_occur_total);
    }//getTotalFeatureOccurances

    private Hashtable<String, Double> feat_occur_total;

}//TextAnalyzer
```

Comment: Btw Hashtable is obsolete - prefer HashMap instead in single threaded code, or ConcurrentHashMap otherwise.

Comment: This is maybe just being pedantic, but if you create the hashtable and never change the private reference in your class, it should also be "final". This makes clear your intention to users of the class, and final variables allow the compiler to perform optimizations that it may not otherwise be able to perform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
feat_occur_total.clear();
```

Clears the Hashtable. Since you returned a reference to the original variable, you cleared the Hashtable itself, not a copy. So returning it again will return the cleared Hashtable.

Comment: It's `Hashtable` with little `t` :)

Comment: Huge help.  I didn't realize it returns a reference to the Hashtable, very good to know.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Your getter is returning a reference to the private `feat_occur_total` field, not a copy. After this, both the `TextAnalyzer.feat_occur_total` reference and the reference returned by the getter refer to the **same instance**. You are calling `clear()` using the reference returned from the getter, which clears the map that both the code snippet at the top and the `TextAnalyzer` instance refer to.